# How can i add multiple handles in d3 slider?

Tags: d3.js

Is this is any solution to achieve this functionality through d3 slider.

[Screenshot that want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS18g.png)

Here i need to add handles as per the values in the text box.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/ac350e2ba0f486384483f456d20797a4

Comment: sorry i'am new on d3.js so may be i'am wrong but i do not need min max functionality for this,i just need to add as many as handles on the position what i entered in the text box.

Comment: Can you post code of what you have already tried @AshishSharma?